# Cannot upload APK for no reason on the new Play Console

Tags: phonegap, google-play-console, cordova-android

I have been struggling with this for two days now.

I am using phonegap 9.0.0 with cordova-android 9.0.0.

The build of the APK is going well, i can run the app on my android phone.

When i upload my APK to the new Google Play Console it only says it cannot import the APK "Please try again later". No other reason.

I have tried everything :

- Removing all plugins, build and try to upload
- Removing cordova-android and adding it again
- Updating every plugin
- and so on...

Is anyone else having the same issue ?
Is it something to do with phonegap/cordova-android ?
Is it something to do with the Google Play Console ?

If someone could help me on that one they would be very welcome !

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This error is so generic that I doubt you'll get much help here. You should contact directly the Play developer support. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en

Comment: same issue here? Is it a server problem on their side? I tried to rename my file which is a .aab by the way without success. My app is a react-native app...

Comment: I tried to change the grade version, the java version used to compile. no results.

Comment: @Pierre I think you're right. I contacted them 5 business days ago actually, no response so far.
I'll tell you if I have one.